# List of listings overflows width of page

Tags: table-of-contents, listings

<strike>*I tried to make working example on sharelatex but could not reproduce the issue.*</strike> Thanks to Torbjørn T.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{listings,showframe} 
\begin{document} 
\lstlistoflistings 
\setcounter{page}{99999} 
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=bla] foo bar 
\end{lstlisting} \end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: MWE compiled]

---

Where List of figures works just fine.

I dug in to template and found these commands (that I can not google out) that are used for list of figures:

```
\newlength{\mylenf}
\settowidth{\mylenf}{\cftfigpresnum}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{\dimexpr\mylenf+3em}
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{\dimexpr\mylenf+3em}
```

Any hints?

Comment: I don't know which documentclass you're using, but this example seems to reproduce the behaviour: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{listings,showframe} \begin{document} \lstlistoflistings 
\setcounter{page}{99999} \begin{lstlisting}[caption=bla] foo bar 
 \end{lstlisting} \end{document}`

Comment: I am using `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{listings}`, and thanks I will add that to the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're already (I assume) using `tocloft`, you can add

```
\cftsetpnumwidth{2.5em}
```

after loading that package. This sets the width of the box for the page numbers in the list of `<stuff>`. Using this does mean that the dots stop before the narrower page numbers though:

[image]

Note also that if you don't load `tocloft` (and comment out the `\cftsetpnumwidth`) in the example below, the list of figures will demonstrate the same behaviour, of the wide page number extending into the margin. `tocloft` seems to fix that for the list of figures, but not for the list of listings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{showframe} % to showtext area
\usepackage{tocloft}
\cftsetpnumwidth{2.5em} % set width of box for page numbers
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\lstlistoflistings
\clearpage
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=bla]
foo bar
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{figure}
\caption{A}
\end{figure}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{99999}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=bla]
foo bar
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{figure}
\caption{A}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```